# Sync existing local images Amazon S3

Tags: assets, s3, amazon

I installed "Amazon S3" in a website. Is there anyway so that I can sync existing local images to Amazon S3?

Answer (score 1):

if you've already set up a volume with your local assets, you can set up another one for s3 and simply drag and drop them over in the "files" section.